# Creating Jinja variables/filters similar to loop.cycle()

Tags: python, templates, jinja2

I'm trying to create a custom Jinja variable that will cycle through a list of values each time it is used. This is similar to `loop.cycle('a','b','c')`, except that I'm not inside a `for` loop.

**Example:**

```
list = ['val1','val2','val3']  
{{ list|next }}  
{{ list|next }}  
{{ list|next }}  
{{ list|next }}
```

**Output:**

```
val1  
val2  
val3  
val1
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Jinja2, since v2.1, allows loop unbound cycling, [as the documentation shows.](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#cycler)

In your example, you would do something like this:

```
{% set cycling_list = cycler('val1', 'val2', 'val3') %}
{{ cycling_list.next() }}  
{{ cycling_list.next() }}  
{{ cycling_list.next() }}
```

There's also [cycler.reset](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#cycler.reset), and [cycler.current](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#cycler.current).

Comment: Thanks.  I swear I read that documentation a dozen times and I never saw that.